# file_put_contents leads to duplicate entries

Tags: php, file-io

**This is my code:**

```
if(isset($_GET['term']) && $_GET['term'] != ""){
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/some/path/protocoll.txt', chr(10) . date('D M j H:i:s Y', time()) . ';;;' . $_GET['term'], FILE_APPEND);
}
```

I used alerts and echos and it seems that only `file_put_contents` is called twice.

**In the log file I find the following:**

```
Thu Feb 2 12:19:34 2013;;;term  
Thu Feb 2 12:19:35 2013;;;term
```

**PHP version is 5.2.17. My `.htaccess` file contains:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /fehler_404.html
```

If I put the function at the end of the PHP file (after `</html>`) it is only called once. On all other places I get duplicate entries.

Do

**Cleaned access_log:**

```
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /path/wLayout/structure/wScript.js HTTP/1.1" 200 21207 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:47 +0100] "GET /path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen HTTP/1.1" 200 14944 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /path/wLayout/structure/wScript.js HTTP/1.1" 200 21207 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /path/wLayout/structure/wStyleselector.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1526 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /weblication/wGui/wScripts/wb_lg_cc_dd.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1848 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /weblication/wGui/wScripts/wb_mb_cc_dd.js HTTP/1.1" 200 11159 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /path/wLayout/design/style/design.css HTTP/1.1" 200 9577 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /path/wLayout/design/style/nav.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3914 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /wLayout/design/style/solr/solr_style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1807 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /wLayout/design/style/solr/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css HTTP/1.1" 200 30852 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/Core.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6588 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/Manager.jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1007 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/Parameter.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/AbstractWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2171 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/AbstractTextWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2137 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/ResultWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1158 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/jquery-1.9.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 92629 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/jquery.livequery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6688 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/PagerWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7448 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/ParameterStore.js HTTP/1.1" 200 11093 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/AbstractFacetWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 8383 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/TagcloudWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1020 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/CurrentSearchWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1270 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/TextWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 437 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/AutocompleteTermWidget.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6118 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/solr_functions.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3577 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 235845 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:49 +0100] "GET /wLayout/structure/solr/AbstractManager.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4588 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:48 +0100] "GET /path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen HTTP/1.1" 200 28300 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:50 +0100] "GET /wLayout/design/img/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 7364 "http://www.example.com/path/volltextsuche/suchergebnisse.php?action=search&configurationId=path.volltextsuche&term=system&button=Suchen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Feb/2013:12:58:50 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.7.1" www.example.com
```

The problem seems to be the AJAX request which updates the page with the search results. I found another way. In the file which sends the request to the search engine I make a AJAX request to my PHP file where I extract the keywords ... This seems to work and so the question is answered.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: @MarkoD: Which code? The complete file? Everything is working fine except of the `file_put_contents` ...

Comment: What is the filename where is this document located and what is the URL. I guess that your .htaccess is doging this. Can you diasble your .htaccess temporarily? And remove all other from your code and run your file. If you create a script temp.php that contains only first three lines you posted, i think it will call file_put_contents only one.

Comment: @iiro: The file name where the posted code is located is called `suchergebnisse.php` and the `protocoll.txt` is located in the same folder. I disabled `.htaccess` but it is still the same issue.

Comment: do you have access to your web server's access log ?

Comment: @iiro: Here you are (see my edited question). Line 3 and line 31 seems to have duplicate calls. But why?

Comment: Clearly your code is getting run more than once.  We'll need more code if we are to be able to tell you why.  Most likely there's some loop it's inside of, but we won't know without more code.  Just the php should be sufficient unless you have meta redirects or something in the html.

Comment: @testing and remove all html-tags to see if it works or not

Comment: @starshine531: There is nothing special in the php scripts itself (I checked it now). There is no much left if I clear out all html code. My assumption is that the integrated jQuery (Ajax) is causing the page to reload with the search results. If someone is interested it's about the solar search. I would find a new way to log the search queries here.

Comment: Then put your logging line at the top of your code that handles the POST from the search.  You should be able to get all your search details there and then it wouldn't do it twice.

Comment: @starshine531: Thanks for your suggestion. A form send the values to my `suchergebnisse.php` file. I put it on the first line and  I still got duplicate entries. Only if I put it at the end (after `</html>`) it wouldn't produce duplicates. But I found another way. In the file which sends the request to the search engine I make a ajax request to my php file where I extract the keywords ... This seems to work and so the question is answered.

Comment: Glad to help and glad you got it working too. :)